# Lisp divisibility

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

`(disivible '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)).This is what I've made so far:

```
(defun divisible(n)
    (cond ((eq n 0) nill) (eq(rem n 3) 0) t )('else 0)))
```

But I'm new in lisp and I don't know how to make it not show me the numbers divisible by 3 but just add the numbers and show me in result. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 5):

```
(defun divisible (num-list)
  (reduce #'+
          (remove-if-not #'zerop
                         num-list
                         :key (lambda (x)
                                (mod x 3)))))
```

Comment: In Scheme, with [SRFI 26](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-26/srfi-26.html), you can write the lambda as `(cut mod <> 3)`. Someone should write an equivalent macro in CL. ;-)

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: call me old-fashioned, but I prefer the plain LAMBDA, instead of just another syntax for functions and how to call them. Also 'improving' functional syntax with macros does not feel right. I think this exposes bad style (replacing core Lisp with something slightly different) and does not help maintainable software. It is just clever in a self-defeating way.

Answer (score 4):

Since `apply` may not work with long lists, here's a `loop` version:

```
(defun divisible (lst)
  (loop for i in lst when (zerop (rem i 3)) sum i))
```

or, using `reduce`

```
(defun divisible (lst)
  (reduce '+ lst :key (lambda (i) (if (zerop (rem i 3)) i 0))))
```

a recursive version

```
(defun divisible (lst)
  (if (null lst)
    0
    (let ((i (car lst)))       
      (if (zerop (rem i 3))
        (+ i (divisible (cdr lst)))
        (divisible (cdr lst))))))
```

or the more clumsy tail-recursive version

```
(defun divisible (lst)
  (labels 
      ((sub (lst res)
         (if (null lst)
           res
           (let ((i (car lst)))
             (sub 
              (cdr lst) 
              (if (zerop (rem i 3)) (+ i res) res))))))
    (sub lst 0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun sum3s (x) (loop for i in x :if (= (mod i 3) 0) :sum i))
```

This is another variation of the above answers.

Answer (score 0):

filtering `remove-if-not` and apply `+`

```
(defun divisible (num-list)
  (apply #'+ (remove-if-not #'(lambda(x)(zerop (rem x 3))) num-list)))
```

Comment: Don't use APPLY. Use REDUCE. Apply is for applying functions to parameter as lists. Parameter lists have a possibly small lengths restriction. REDUCE is for computing a value from an arbitrary long list.